# On Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) reserved instance, can I launch ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Accidentally while purchasing reserved instance, I have selected Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) as the platform. But I want to run Ubuntu as the OS on the instance that I am going to launch.

Is it possible to launch an Ubuntu instance over a Linux/UNIX (Amazon VPC) reserved instance? Or amazon would not let me do that by billing it separately?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu is considered to be a "Linux/UNIX" instance for reserved instance purposes. The only Linux platforms that get separate special handling are Amazon's RHEL and SUSE offerings.